# Add footer SVG file using Kendo UI

Tags: c#, .net, svg, kendo-ui, footer

I need to add a footer to a SVG file using a third party application called Kendo UI.

I am calling the Kendo UI API from a .net Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just add hack it a bit and replace the last  tag
with the following

```
<g><text><tSpan>...</tSpan></text></g></svg>
```